# Editable grid supporting XML data storage with row editing/sorting/reordering

Tags: php, javascript

Is there an editable grid made for xml with a sensible api for editing, sorting, reordering rows of text, numeric, hyperlink data?  This HTML page requires a grid to show and edit data stored in an XML file. I'd like to have a grid that allows row selection and deletion.  I've looked at

- DHTMLXgrid: There is no documentation on how to save data to XML files.  If you have information about to do that, I might have another look at it.
- Flexgrid: Doesn't do editing yet.
- DrasticTools: No XML example, and interface non-standard.
- slickgrid: A lot of the examples supplied are broken.  Can't show that the features are actually there.  Seems like only the initiated can use this grid.
- jqgrid: Prefer to stay away from that one.

Are there alternatives?  Either javascript or PHP would be OK.

Comment: I'm curious, which examples did you find broken in SlickGrid.  I've taken a look at all of them and one (fixed headers) appears to be broken by a recent change, but the rest of them seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dhtmlxgrid does the job wery well.  Found information on using the api to get a text string with the current grid content.  From this I was able to save to XML.  More information is given here [Dhtmlxgrid: Getting an xml string of grid data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231076/dhtmlxgrid-getting-an-xml-string-of-grid-data)